# Block until Complete Count

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I am using Redis streams and need to block my clients until there are at least say X number of messages in the stream and return when it reaches that X count..
Is there any way to achieve this?

EG: `XREADGROUP GROUP G1 C2 COUNT 10 BLOCK 0 STREAMS L >` until all 10 messages have arrived in the stream key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT` specifies the *maximum* number of elements to return per stream, if there are any. If the streams are empty (and the `BLOCK` option was used), the consumer blocks. Once there's a single incoming message, the blocking is released with that message. So no, you can't block until `COUNT` messages are read. But you can probably group messages on the application level.

See [`XREAD`](https://redis.io/commands/xread) for more details.

Comment: For doing it on application side i made my library https://www.npmjs.com/package/relief-valve , but i was looking for debouncing message on redis server itself in either time or count dimension..just wrote a lib for that